# Is it possible to dynamically change a background image in react native?

Tags: react-native

I've tried this for a while, this isn't a runnable snippet (it's react native) but still a straightforward one.

Basically my app component returns an image background and the app's body:

```js
return ( <ImageBackground 
                    source={{ uri: source }} 
                    resizeMode="cover"          
                    style={styles.image}
                    >

             {body}
  
        </ImageBackground>
    );
```

Now I expected ImageBackground to change when I change the `source` in a set state, but it seems that is not possible with react native.

Has anyone achieved this or has advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

##### Class Component

```
onChangeImgBackground = (index) => {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            source: { uri: 'https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/posts/css-advanced-background-images/cover.jpg' }
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground
                style={styles.container}
                imageStyle={styles.backgroundImage}
                source={this.state.source}>
                <SafeAreaView edges={['top', 'bottom']} style={styles.content}>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
```

##### Functional Component

```
const [source, setSource] = React.useState({uri: ''}) // or require('img/path')

    onChangeImgBackground = (index) => {
            setSource({ uri: 'https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/posts/css-advanced-background-images/cover.jpg' })
    }
        
        
            return (
                <ImageBackground
                    style={styles.container}
                    imageStyle={styles.backgroundImage}
                    source={source}>
                    <SafeAreaView edges={['top', 'bottom']} style={styles.content}>
                    </SafeAreaView>
                </ImageBackground>
            )
```

Comment: this won't work the problem is that it's replaced at build time, and won't make any calls afterwards. the only way is to load a few images in advance which is what i ended up doing

Comment: What is replaced at build time? Can you be more specific?